# How do I block SSH connections except those originating from within a /29 block of IP's or LAN? (CentOS 7 and Ubuntu 12)

Tags: ubuntu, centos, ssh, firewall

I see thousands of failed login attempts on our servers and want to do what I can to prevent a successful one from the bad guys.  I want to block anyone not originating from a /29 block we own from being allowed to SSH into our servers.

I have disabled root login, password authentication, installed fail2ban, and instituted SSH keys.  Is this a redundant step or a decent layer of protection?  If the later, what is a way I can achieve this?

Comment: Old!  It doesn't matter for this, but update your software sometimes.  It's fun and secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the logic to your firewall such as:

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/29 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

Comment: When I tried that first line I got, iptables v1.4.21: Couldn't load target `ALLOW':No such file or directory

Comment: It should be `ACCEPT`, not `ALLOW`.  I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just create two sections `Match` in the config that define required behaviour:

```
Match Address 11.22.33.44/29
   AllowUsers *

Match Address *
   AllowUsers
```